# Searching inside element seems not to work in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Finding element inside another element seems not to work as expected.

I have a table through which I would like to iterate and update record if certain cell in a row is empty. I am getting a list of webelements to iterate through.

It correctly iterates through rows which I have confirmed via using print statements. Inside each row I want to check if certain cell is empty and update it if it is.

```
for _ in range(len(total_records_to_update)):
    for record in self.driver.find_elements(*XPATH):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(
                lambda d: record.find_element_by_xpath('//td[10][normalize-space(.)="' + text_in_cell + '"]')
            )
            print("Cell is not empty, checking next one")
            continue
        except TimeoutException:
            update_record()
            break # page is refreshed, hence the outer loop
```

This code updates just the first record and skips the rest. I see that these records are iterated over but WebDriverWait returns True instantaneously. I also tried the following with the same results:

```
WebDriverWait(record, 3).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((
        By.XPATH,
        "//td[10][normalize-space(.)='" + text_in_cell + "']"
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using double slash `//` you're selecting the element start from the root, to select current child `td` try using the `./` or `./td[10]....`

Comment: This seems to work, even though it's not very intuitive. I am already passing webelement for search function. Is it the only way to search inside webelement?

Comment: other than xpath? try `lambda d: record.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(10)').text == text_in_cell`

Comment: I meant more like a relative xpath ('//'), without attaching to the element root.